# Mapping Letters to Numbers in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of strings consisting of `n` letters, for example `"ABCDEF"`

I need to map this to some unique number. Of course, the intuitive approach is to extract all single letters `letter` and then match them one by one to the corresponding number via

```
match(letter,LETTERS)
```

But that leads to too large numbers for large `n`, because I need 2 digits for every single one of the letters (from `01`to `26`).

My idea is now to match each *combination* of strings to a unique number between `1`and `26^n`, making use of the fact that `26^n` has less than `2n` digits for large `n`.

For example for `n=4` we get `"AAAA" -> 1` and `"ZZZZ" -> 26^4`

How can I do this in R?

Comment: are the strings inside the vector unique as well?

Comment: Yes the are, but it should work when new data comes in, so sorting won´t do

Comment: There is a function for this already, try: `charToRaw("ABCDEF")`

Comment: @zx8754 But that doesn´t save digits, I still need two for every single letter

Comment: What do you mean "save"?

Comment: This method needs `2n` digits, if I match using my method I only need the number of digits that `26^n` has, which is less for large `n`

Comment: Yes, my method will give more digits, but we don't have "getting all combinations, assign value for each then map" step.

Comment: Maybe that was unclear, but what I meant is: `26^n` has less *digits* than `2n` for large `n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to code the letters like below

```
f <- function(letter) sum((match(unlist(strsplit(letter,"")),LETTERS)-1)*26**((nchar(letter)-1):0))+1
```

such that

```
> f("AAAA")
[1] 1

> f("AABC")
[1] 29

> f("ZZZZ")
[1] 456976
```

Answer (score 0):

While this may be clever,  using a factor may be much simpler and far easier to understand.  You also get to keep the string format close to hand, while getting the space saving of it being encoded as an integer.

If you need integers in a database (which will do joins better on them) then you can cast the factor to an int with `as.integer(factor_column)` and you'll have the integer variants too.

What you'll loose is the determinism of the mapping, which may be important for you in the DB world if this is anything more than a one-off data load.

Comment: That is true, but I need numbers because the data will be read into a database and everyone told me that it is more efficient to join on integers rather than characters. So basically I am trying to map uniquely to integers while keeping the numbers as small as possible (otherwise R can't handle it)